# functions.database.DeltaSnapshot#changed unexpected result

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using the changed() function in some functions and the result is not expected given the documentation.

I added a few tests to the following file to illustrate the issue.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/master/src/providers/database.ts

```
it('should be false when the current value has not changed', () => {
  populate({ a: { b: 'c' } }, { a: { b: 'c' } });
  expect(subject.child('a').changed()).to.be.false;
});

it('should be false when the current value has not changed, child path exists', () => {
  populate({ a: { b: 'c' } }, { a: { b: 'c' } });
  expect(subject.child('a/b').changed()).to.be.false;
});

it('should be false when the current value has not changed, child path does not exist', () => {
  populate({ a: { b: 'c' } }, { a: { b: 'c' } });
  expect(subject.child('a/d').changed()).to.be.false;
});
```

The first 2 tests fail, but i expected the changed() function to return false. Am i misunderstand the documentation?

Refs
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot#changed

Comment: Do you have live examples of this failing in the real world, or only in unit tests? `populate()` isn't doing what you seem to think -- the first argument is old data, the second is the **delta** to new data. Anything that hasn't changed shouldn't be in the second argument, which is why the tests are failing.

Comment: yeah just unit tests, that makes sense, the signature is `data, delta`.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Can you provide your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the unit tests of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions, the signature of `populate` is `populate(data, delta)`. That is, the original data and the **change** from the original data.

When the SDK checks for changes, it does so by seeing if the value is present in the `delta` payload. In a deployed function, anything that hasn't changed is explicitly not sent in the `delta` payload.